# How do I place an image (or text) below two or more words in a paragraph using CSS only?

Tags: html, css

In this example I need to couple an image (or sometimes a word) with two words in a sentence, so that the image shows below these two words. The example comes from a grammar textbook (in Swedish). The only thing I accomplish with this is that the images end up over the text. Does anyone have an idea how to go about this?

[Example from printed textbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Dt8H.png)

HTML:

```
<p><strong>Verb</strong>: <em>Mamma <span class="pilvIMG">log <u>brett</u></span>.</em></p>
<p><strong>Adjektiv</strong>: <em>Hon var <span class="pilhIMG"><u>mycket</u> glad</span>!</em></p>
<p><strong>Andra adverb</strong>: <em>Sven sprang <span class="pilhIMG"><u>otroligt</u> snabbt</span>.</em></p>
```

CSS:

```
.pilvIMG {
background-image: url(pilv.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
display: inline-block;
}
.pilhIMG {
background-image: url(pilh.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `before`pseudo-element.
In the current code below i used the `content` attribute to show you how it's positioned, but you could also use an `background-image` for the pseudo-element.

Though you would still need to define the content, just let it empty like `content: "";`

and you'd propably want to adjust the `top` and `left` attributes, but this solution should help you on your way.

edit: NOTE that i set the position for the span classes to relative

```css
.pilvIMG,.pilhIMG{
  position:relative;
}

.pilvIMG:before{
  content: "->";
  position:absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}

.pilhIMG:before{
 content: "<-";
 position:absolute;
 left: 10px;
 top:10px;
}
```

```html
<p><strong>Verb</strong>: <em>Mamma <span class="pilvIMG">log <u>brett</u></span>.</em></p>
<p><strong>Adjektiv</strong>: <em>Hon var <span class="pilhIMG"><u>mycket</u> glad</span>!</em></p>
<p><strong>Andra adverb</strong>: <em>Sven sprang <span class="pilhIMG"><u>otroligt</u> snabbt</span>.</em></p>
```